# how to set min value for highchart bullet chart to start in that point

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want a bullet chart start at a point like 150.(you can see in the bellow image)

[image]

but when I trying to set pointStart value for bullet chart it dose not work.

Comment: What code have you written already? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `min` value on the yAxis (because bullet chart is inverted).

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/skLd7qf0/

```
  yAxis: {
    min: 150,
    plotBands: [{
      from: 150,
      to: 225,
      color: '#999'
    }, {
      from: 225,
      to: 9e9,
      color: '#bbb'
    }],
  },
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.min